# jQuery .prop() returns undefined, while .attr() works as expected for data-*

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr, prop

I am simply trying to get a couple of properties from two elements. Getting the property `value` from the `input` element works as expected. The problem is with getting the property `data-detail` property from the `button` element. It returns `undefined` when using `.prop()`, but works as expected when using `.attr()`.

Can anyone explain this odd behaviour I am witnessing?

**HTML**

```
<div class="formRow">
    <label for="firstName">First name</label>
    <div class="detailsControlBtns">
        <button id="editFirstName" class="btn ctaBtn greenBtn editBtn">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn ctaBtn greenBtn saveBtn" data-detail="firstName">Save</button>
        <button id="closeFirstName" class="btn ctaBtn greyBtn closeBtn">Close</button>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="[+firstName+]" readonly>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".saveBtn").on("click", function() {
    var saveBtn = $(this);
    // The following statement yields undefined. When using .attr() it works as expected.
    var detail = saveBtn.prop("data-detail");
    var relevantInput = saveBtn.parent().next();
    // The following statement works as expected.
    var value = relevantInput.prop("value");
    // ...
});
```

Comment: What version of jquery you are using?

Comment: @LearningPhase jquery-1.11.3.min.js

Comment: With data attributes I suggest to use saveBtn.data("detail")

Comment: @misher I didn't know about that, thank you - it does work as expected.

Comment: @LearningPhase isn't my data-detail considered a property? If not, why not?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's because there's no  **data-detail** *property* on HTML element.

**Here is a quick explanation for [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/), [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) :**
**DOM** element is an *object* which has `methods`, and `properties` (from the `DOM`) and `attributes`(from the rendered `HTML`). Some of those `properties` get their `initial value` by the `attributes` 
 `id->id, class->className, title->title, style->style etc.`
**Consider this element:** `<input type="checkbox" checked data-detail="somedata" >`
The **result** of the following would be:

```
$('input').prop('id'); // => " "-empty string, property id exist on the element (defined by DOM) , but is not set.
$('input').attr('id');// => undefined - doesn't exist.
```

---

**If you do the following:**

```
$('input').attr('id',"someID");
$('input').prop('id'); // =>  "someID"
$('input').attr('id'); // =>  "someID"
```

**And also:**

```
$('input').prop('id',"someOtherID");
$('input').prop('id');// =>  "someOtherID"
$('input').attr('id');// =>  "someOtherID"
```

> So,  some attributes and properties have **1:1 mapping**. (change of
>   the attr result change of the prop and vice versa).

---

**Consider the following:** `<input type="text" data-detail="somedata" value="someValue">`

```
$('input').prop('value'); // =>  "someValue"
$('input').val();         // =>  "someValue"
$('input').attr('value'); // =>  "someValue"
```

**And if you do:**

```
$('input').prop('value','newVal');

// or

$('input').val('newVal');

$('input').prop('value'); // => "newVal"    -value of the property
$('input').val();         // => "newVal"    -value of the property
$('input').attr('value'); // => "someValue" -value of the attr didn't change, since in this case it is not 1:1 mapping (change of the prop value doesn't reflect to the attribute value).
```

---

### **Case with the** **[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**

**1) How to get:**

**-** Have in mind that `attribute name` is `data-*`  and `property name` is `dataset`, so:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-detail="somedata" >
```

```
 $('input')[0].dataset; //=> [object DOMStringMap] { detail: "somedata"}
 $('input')[0].dataset.detail; // => "somedata"
 $('input').prop('dataset'); //=>[object DOMStringMap] { detail: "somedata"}
 $('input').prop('dataset').detail; // => "somedata"
 $('input').data('detail'); // => "somedata"
 $('input').attr('data-detail');  //  => "somedata"
```

**2) How to set:**

**I)** `$('input').prop('dataset').detail='newData';`

```
 $('input').prop('dataset');  //=> [object DOMStringMap] { detail: "newData"}
 $('input').prop('dataset').detail; // => "newData"
 $('input').attr('data-detail'); // => "newData"
 $('input').data('detail'); // => "newData"
```

**II)** `$('input').attr('data-detail','newData');`

```
 $('input').prop('dataset');  //=> [object DOMStringMap] { detail: "newData"}
 $('input').prop('dataset').detail; // => "newData"
 $('input').attr('data-detail'); // => "newData"
 $('input').data('detail'); // => "newData"
```

> So you can see that here is 1:1 mapping, attr change reflects prop and
>   vice versa.

**But check the third way:**

**III)** `$('input').data('detail','newData');`

```
 $('input').prop('dataset'); // =>  [object DOMStringMap] { detail: "somedata"}
 $('input').prop('dataset').detail; // => "somedata"
 $('input').attr('data-detail'); // => "somedata"
 $('input').data('detail');  // => "newData"    <-----******
```

So, what is happening up here?

> `$(elem).data(key, value)` does not change the `HTML5 data-*` attributes
>   of the element. It stores its values in `$.cache` internally.

So for getting `data-*` you would never go wrong with `.data()` :

```
$(".saveBtn").on("click", function() {
    var saveBtn = $(this);
    var detail = saveBtn.data("detail");
    var relevantInput = saveBtn.parent().next();
    var value = relevantInput.prop("value");

});
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the very detailed answer, I have learned a lot.

Comment: Thanks, It's more helpful than API's document