# jQuery, data() not updating data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the below piece of HTML and the associated jQuery. The `html`function is working correctly but the `data` function isn't affecting the HTML at all, I can't for the life of me figure it out, no errors in the browser at all.

**HTML**

```
<span id="usernameStatus" data-valid="0">x</span>
```

**jQuery**

`data` is returned by an AJAX call, it will only ever be `true` or `false`.

```
function validUsername(data)
{        
    if (data === 'true') {
        $("#usernameStatus").html("y").data("valid", 1);
    } else {
        $("#usernameStatus").html("x").data("valid", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8707226/6188402)

Comment: Pretty sure that the data function is not working as you would expect. Im pretty sure jquery makes a copy/ref/thing of the data attributes so your changing that not the attr. If you look at the .data for the same element after you changed it you will see its changed but the html attr will remain the same.

Comment: You can find a good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663690/jquery-prop-returns-undefined-while-attr-works-as-expected-for-data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per jQuery API Docs

> The .data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks.

The `.data()` method *will not* modify the existing DOM node, but will only be retrievable via calling of `$selector.data()`. Your DOM elements don't change, just the data attached to them.

Answer (score 2):

The `.data()` method does not modify the DOM element's attribute. However, data is still saved  via. `$selector.data( key, value );` and can be retrieved via. `$selector.data( key );`

In order to add an attribute to a DOM element, you will likely want to use the [.attr() method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). With `.attr()`, an attribute can be attached to an element  via. `$selector.attr( key, value );` and can be retrieved via. `$selector.attr( key );`

```
    validUsername(data) {       
        if (data === 'true') {
            $("#usernameStatus").html("y").attr("data-valid", 1);
        } else {
            $("#usernameStatus").html("x").attr("data-valid", 0);
        }
    }
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ov5ye7uz/3/)

One of the advantages of using `.attr()` instead of `.data()` is the ability to find all elements with an attribute (and value) via. the `$('[key="value"]')` selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$("#usernameStatus").attr('data-valid','1');
```

Instead of ising .html() which returns inner content of an element .