# How to set onClick event to a figure or image element which is lazy-loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, tampermonkey, userscripts

Well, I'm trying to set an onClick event with jQuery on a image to open it on another tab after left click it.
But it looks like because the [website](https://revistaglamour.globo.com/Celebridades/noticia/2019/08/lena-dunham-tenta-dar-selinho-em-brad-pitt-nao-consegue-e-fotografos-registram-tudo.html) has [lazy loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) images, my script is not working. Even with the awesome [waitForKeyElements script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195658/run-greasemonkey-script-on-the-same-page-multiple-times/11197969#11197969), which most of the times save me when the page has AJAX'ed content, I couldn't achieve what I'm looking for.

Please check my code below:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @include     https://revista*.globo.com/*.html
// @version     1.0
// @require     https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js
// @require     https://gist.githubusercontent.com/BrockA/2625891/raw/9c97aa67ff9c5d56be34a55ad6c18a314e5eb548/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       GM_openInTab
// @run-at      document-idle
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements("image.lazy-loaded.lazy-loaded", clickableImage, false);

function clickableImage (jNode) {

     jNode.each ( function () {
         var jThis = $(this);
         console.log( JSON.stringify( jThis ) );
         var imgLink = jThis.prop ("data-src");
         console.log( imgLink );

         jThis.on( "click", function() {

             GM_openInTab(imgLink);

         });


     } );

}
```

I'm using Firefox v68.0.1 with Tampermonkey v4.9.5941

Thanks in advance.

---

**As [this answer from the duplicate question explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36663776/805070) and the comment, I achieved what I expected with the code below**

```
waitForKeyElements("image.lazy-loaded.lazy-loaded", clickableImage, false);

function clickableImage (jNode) {

     var imgLink = jNode.data ("src");   
     jNode.on( "click", function() {

         GM_openInTab(imgLink);

     });
};
```

Comment: i guess settimeout won't work in this case?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried, since WaitForKeyElements is based on setInterval I couldn't see how it could show different results.

Comment: `"data-src` is not a property, it is a data attribute -- a special subset of attributes that are handled separately by both browsers and by jQuery.  Use `var imgLink = jThis.data ("src");`.  That's the biggest problem with that code but there are several others.  For example WFKE only ever passes one node at a time to the callback. So, `jNode` will always be length 1 and `.each()` is a waste of effort.

Comment: God bless you Brock Adams. Thank you now it worked.

Comment: You're welcome; glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on` to bind event handlers to elements that don't yet exist. For example if the elements can be eventually found using the jQuery selector `.lazy-loaded`, then you can bind one event handler on a parent element that does exist already (like body) and events will be caught by the handler when they eventually bubble up later:

```
$("body").on("click", ".lazy-loaded", function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

Comment: I tried $("body").on( "click", ".lazy-loaded", function() { the result was the same